# How to convert a numeric string with place-value commas into an integer?

Tags: python

In Python, what is a clean and elegant way to convert strings like "1,374" or "21,000,000" to int values like 1374 or 21000000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends where you get your number from.

If the number you are trying to convert comes from user input, use `locale.atoi()`. That way, the number will be parsed in a way that is consistent with the user's settings and thus expectations.

If on the other hand you read it, let's say, from a file, that always uses the same format, use `int("1,234".replace(",", ""))` or `int("1.234".replace(".", ""))` depending on your situation. This is not only easier to read and debug, but it's not affected by the user's locale setting, so your parser will work on any system.

Answer (score 4):

[`locale.atoi()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.atoi), after setting an appropriate locale.

Comment: +1 This is better than just replacing commas with empty-strings, because in some locales commas are used as decimal separators, while periods play the part of delimiting the thousands, millions etc.

Comment: Depends what you're trying to parse. User input? Or a file with a fixed format (say a CSV you get from a legacy system)? Not the same. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s="1,374"
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.atoi(s)
1374
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int("1,374".replace(",",""))
```