# Convert number strings with commas in pandas DataFrame to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains numbers as strings with commas for the thousands marker. I need to convert them to floats.

```
a = [['1,200', '4,200'], ['7,000', '-0.03'], [ '5', '0']]
df=pandas.DataFrame(a)
```

I am guessing I need to use locale.atof. Indeed

```
df[0].apply(locale.atof)
```

works as expected. I get a Series of floats.

But when I apply it to the DataFrame, I get an error.

```
df.apply(locale.atof)
```

> TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to ", u'occurred at index 0')

and

```
df[0:1].apply(locale.atof)
```

gives another error:

> ValueError: ('invalid literal for float(): 1,200', u'occurred at index 0')

So, how do I convert this `DataFrame` of strings to a DataFrame of floats?

Comment: Old question, but the OP is getting that error because `apply` on a DataFrame passes a whole **column** to the function as a series (in this case `locale.atof`, which expects a string). If you use the `applymap` method that @AndyHayden does in the answer below, you should be able to do this just fine.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

If you're [reading in from csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) then you can use the [thousands arg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667788/1240268):

```
df.read_csv('foo.tsv', sep='\t', thousands=',')
```

This method is likely to be more efficient than performing the operation as a separate step.

---

You need to [set the locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308488/1240268) first:

```
In [ 9]: import locale

In [10]: from locale import atof

In [11]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')
Out[11]: 'en_GB.UTF-8'

In [12]: df.applymap(atof)
Out[12]:
      0        1
0  1200  4200.00
1  7000    -0.03
2     5     0.00
```

Comment: I should have said that I did set the locale. I still get the error.

Comment: But I am using df.read_fwf, and that has the " thousands=',' " option too, which works. Thanks.

Comment: Then again, why does df.applymap(atof) work for you but not me? My locale is 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Comment: @pheon that should work too, running the setlocale function should get atof working (in the referenced answer they are in en_US locale and it works)...

Comment: @pheon if it doesn't that's weird. Presumably it doesn't work for `atof('3,000')` by itself / in vanilla python? (You could post a separate question about just that, without the pandas references.)

Comment: I voted this up for the 'thousands' argument tip for the read_csv function. That worked great for me.

Comment: I wanted to add that you can also use "decimal=',' " if you're dealing with floats.

Comment: I find that (for csv files) it worked when doing this `df = pd.read_csv(file='foo.csv', sep=',', thousands=',')`. the difference being with the `sep=` argument as a `,` and not `\t`.

Comment: Should be `pd.read_csv` not `df.read_csv`.

Answer (score 65):

You can convert one column at a time like this :

```
df['colname'] = df['colname'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
```

Comment: With this, I get a Warning: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will*not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.. No idea why it assumes that regex=True

Comment: That's a *horrible* idea. It will convert `0,2` to `2` instead of `0.2`. There's simply no way one can use replacements to parse localized number literals. What about `10,000.0`? What about `10.000,00` ?

Comment: Thank you, @PanagiotisKanavos. Your comment prevented me from tumbling in this major pitfall and continuing to work with heavily messed up data. `pd.Series('0,5').str.replace(',', '').astype(float)` returns 5!

Answer (score 43):

You may use the [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) method:

```
df.iloc[:,:].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
```

This method can remove or replace the comma in the string.

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'", no idea why...

Comment: But this works: `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '').astype(float), axis=1)`

Comment: What if my number have more than one comma? like: "1,099,99", how can I convert it to "'1099.99'"?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for strings such as '-55,00' or '5.500,00' and convert them to floats -55.00 and 5500.00, respectively.

```
df['colname'] = df['colname'].str.replace('.','', regex=True).str.replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)
```