# How to convert a number expressed as a string into float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a column with numbers like "4,3" expressed as data type string into float.

The dataframe:

> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> Int64Index: 19147 entries, 0 to
> 21491 Data columns (total 13 columns):  #   Column
> Non-Null Count  Dtype
> ---  ------              --------------  -----    0   PremiseID           19147 non-null  int64    1   PremiseName         19147 non-null
> object   2   Category            19147 non-null  object   3   Region
> 19147 non-null  object   4   InhabitantsCount    19147 non-null  int64
> 5   DistanceCityCentre  19147 non-null  int64    6   FacebookLikes
> 19147 non-null  float64  7   RatingValue         19147 non-null
> object   8   RatingCount         19147 non-null  int64    9
> OpeningSaturday     19147 non-null  float64  10  ClosingSaturday
> 19147 non-null  float64  11  DrinkItem           19147 non-null
> object   12  Price               19147 non-null  object  dtypes:
> float64(3), int64(4), object(6) memory usage: 2.0+ MB

I've tried:

```
# Convert data types
conv_dict = {
    'FacebookLikes': int,
    'RatingValue': float,
    'Price': int,
}

df = df.astype(conv_dict)
```

The error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4,3'

Comment: You have to replace the comma with a dot and then convert it to float

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert number strings with commas in pandas DataFrame to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float)

Comment: show input dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Create a new conversion func that will take care of this input `4,3`

```
def float_conv(val):
   return float(val.replace(',','.'))
```

and use it

```
conv_dict = {
    'FacebookLikes': int,
    'RatingValue': float_conv,
    'Price': int,
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this as df.RatingValue.replace(',', '.') but with no effect.
When I try your solution as proposed, I'm getting "data type not recognized".
If I try to convert the column directly using float(val.replace()), I get "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>".