# Python Pandas: Can't subtract column values

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with two columns, "value1, value2" for example.
Both are strings (ex: `'100,50'` and `'100,10'`), but there is a part in my code that i have to check if the difference between the two are less or equal to 1.0.

```py
df = df.assign(difference = df['value1'] - df['value2'])
new_df = df [(df.difference <= 1.0)]
```

There is ways to convert string into float type but there are not working.

I tried using pandas.astype(float) and locale.atof in a loop. But the terminal says: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '482,43'`

With

```py
pds.to_numeric(valor_false_df['VR CMS'], downcast="float")
```

it says `ValueError: Unable to parse string "482,43" at position 0.`

How can i make this subtraction? Where am i wrong?

Comment: The answer is here: [Convert number strings with commas in pandas DataFrame to float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22137723/1609514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe pandas is interpreting the comma as a comma, and not as the decimal delimiter. If you replace the comma with a period and then cast as float, it should work (from [a similar StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float)):

```
df['value1'] = df['value1'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df['value2'] = df['value2'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df = df.assign(difference = df['value1'] - df['value2'])
new_df = df [(df.difference <= 1.0)]
```

Comment: i did not know about the "decimal delimiter". thanks.