# Conversion of data types of multiple columns - Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to write the following code and it does not let me to convert the columns  Amount currency,Amount  in to float. Below is my query

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\CustomerData.csv')

parsed = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors="coerce").fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],format="%Y-%d-%m",errors="coerce"))

ordinal = pd.to_numeric(df["Date"], errors="coerce").apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp("1899-12-30")+pd.Timedelta(x, unit="D"))
df["Date"] = parsed.fillna(ordinal)

newdf = df.loc[(df.Type == "Sales Invoice")]

df2 = newdf.groupby(['Date','Customer','Type'])["Amount currency", "Amount"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(float).sum())
```

But i am getting the below error

**could not convert string to float: '10,084.80'**

And in the csv file, I have checked the column contents. But in the number columns, it does not contain any special character.

the below is the general info of my data set

```
Data columns (total 5 columns):
   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   Date             80 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   Customer         80 non-null     object        
 2   Amount currency  80 non-null     object        
 3   Type             80 non-null     object        
 4   Amount           80 non-null     object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(4)
```

These columns, Amount currency and Amount cannot be converted in to float type with the above codes.

These are the steps I did -

1.Importing the data set

2.Cleaning the dte column and arranging the data

3.converting the date column to YYY-MM format

4.creating a group by after selecting the type in to  "Sales Invoice"

5.Group by sum will generate a set of multiple data instead of sum of the values.

For that, need to convert the values in to float

Any one to help?

Thanks

Comment: The code you provided is unreadable. Indent it properly and use line breaks

Comment: Since the value in the column has a comma, it will give error when you convert it into float. May be this could help [Convert number strings with commas in pandas DataFrame to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert number strings with commas in pandas DataFrame to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
df['Amount currency'] = df['Amount currency'].str.replace(r'[^0-9\.]', '', regex=True)
df['Amount currency'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount currency'])
```

The first line will delete any characters that are not a digit or a dot. So, instead of `10,084.80`, you will get '10084.80'. Then, by executing the second line, you will successfully convert that to a float.

Beware, if you have negative numbers (i.e. -10,084.80), the first line will delete the '-' and therefore you'll end up with a positive float. If you need to keep the '-' to have a negative float, just change the regex expression to `r'[^0-9\.\-]'`, which will keep the minus and get you -10084.80.

Comment: Just to clear up, I provided two lines instead of a one liner to keep the principle of readability first.