# Pandas Math bug in one column only, others work

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have a script that I've been using with no issue, all it does is creates a new column with the values increased by 10% until I have hit one column... the only thing is it's all numbers, no spaces or null/NaN or letters and it's doing my head in.

```
df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].multiply(1.1).round()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\Datafeed\datafeed\script.Auscomp.py", line 28, in <module>
    df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].multiply(1.1).round()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 6014, in mul
    return self._flex_method(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5942, in _flex_method
    return op(self, other)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 76, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 202, in __mul__
    return self._arith_method(other, operator.mul)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5819, in _arith_method
    return base.IndexOpsMixin._arith_method(self, other, op)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1381, in _arith_method
    result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 285, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 229, in _na_arithmetic_op
    result = _masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 184, in _masked_arith_op
    result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I'll be honest, I have no idea what any of that log means :(

Comment: plz provide [mre]

Comment: What happens if you do `df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].astype(float).multiply(1.1)`?

Comment: the code i've used on about 20 datafeeds, however on this datafeed it gives this error on only 1 column, works fine on other columns, if I copy this one column, rename or reindex, this one column (or its copies) give this error.

Comment: when i use ```df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].astype(float).multiply(1.1)``` i get this error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,153.00'```

Comment: Okay, in the csv the value is ```1,159.00``` not ```1159``` as expected I'll see if there is a way around it

Comment: A "collum" is the monster which is born when Gollum and Excel have an affair. Yech.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float helps.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much everyone, Adding ``` df = pd.read_csv('source', thousands=',')``` resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate the same error you are getting and got to a conclusion that the DBP_AUS might contain non-numeric data or missing values (NaN), which causes issues when performing arithmetic operations.

To diagnose this issue you can verify the data types and presence of NaN values in the 'DBP_AUS' column using the following commands:

```
print(df['DBP_AUS'].dtype)
```

If the output from the above code is object or

```
print(df['DBP_AUS'].isnull().sum())
```

the output from the above code is 1 it means that there is a non-numeric data in you database and you are applying mathematical operation on it.

So after applying the above snippets your code will look something like this:

```
print(df['DBP_AUS'].dtype) # output of this line will be "object" 

df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].multiply(1.1).round()
```

Comment: so have added those 2 lines and output is "Object" and "0", and thank you for such a fast reply

Comment: Well that clearly mean that there is a non-numeric value in you database, if u remove that u r good to go!

Comment: yeah found csv data is formatting 4 digit numbers ie "1,518.00" instead of "1518" - I'm researching how to remove this formatting now., Again Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your column as numeric with after removing thousand separator:

```
df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].str.replace(r',', '').astype(float).mul(1.1).round()
print(df)

# Output
    DBP_AUS  COST_AUS
0  1,159.00    1275.0
```

Answer (score 0):

i make minimal and reproducible example to solve problem

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, '3,000.1'])
```

s

```
0          1
1          2
2    3,000.1
dtype: object
```

run following code:

```
s.multiply(1.1).round()
```

return error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

becuz '3,000.1' is not float.

run following code

```
out = s.astype('str').str.replace(',', '').astype('float').multiply(1.1).round()
```

out

```
0       1.0
1       2.0
2    3300.0
dtype: float64
```

plz chk dtype of your example and provide [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
before asking

Comment: thanks, very new here and even newer to python/panda, but will definitely try to add examples in the future, the method of reading the CSV was not showing the thousands comma

Answer (score 0):

Massive thanks to the community, with some guidance, we managed to identify the issue as number formatting, by using the following commands;

First to verify no null/NaN or anything other than numbers in the column,

```
print(df['DBP_AUS'].dtype)
print(df['DBP_AUS'].isnull().sum())
```

Output was:

```
Object
0
```

by converting the string to add ".astype(float)":

```
df['COST_AUS'] = df['DBP_AUS'].astype(float).multiply(1.1)
```

revealed a new error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,153.00'
```

With it revealing the '1,153.00', the Column was formatted and this was corrected by adding the thousands to the pd.read.csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('source', thousands=',')
```