# Django conversion of unicode value to float doesn't work

Tags: django, unicode

This is the part of my code where I need to convert a Unicode value to float using `float()`, but I got the exception `invalid literal float()`

```
print("before conversion ",request.POST['prix'])
prix=request.POST['prix']
prixConvert= float(prix)
print("after conversion ")
print(prixConvert)
```

Comment: Please post an example of a number you tried to convert, that causes the error.

Comment: Please check.. this will happen if unicode contains a character other than a number..

Comment: please print request.POST['prix'] and show what you are trying to typecast to float

Comment: When i try to print request.POST['prix'] I got u'10,0'

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308443/how-to-convert-a-numeric-string-with-place-value-commas-into-an-integer) might help.

Comment: Thank you, I tied it & it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment under the question, your "number" actually contains a `,`. That is not a valid character for a `float()` call. You need to convert that into a `.` first.

```
print("before: {}".format(request.POST['prix']))

prix = request.POST['prix'].replace(',', '.')
prixConvert = float(prix)

print("after conversion: {}".format(prixConvert))
```

And better, catch the error and tell the user to supply a valid string

```
try:
    prixConvert = float(prix)
except ValueError:
    print('That was not a valid float number.')
```

If your input is very unreliable, you can add more `.replace()` calls to "clean up" the input before converting, that way you may catch more numbers that are hidden within otherwise invalid input.